# Kotlin "also" function strange warning in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

There is two presumably identical snippets:

```
// Verbose version
val typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, styleable)
block(typedArray)
typedArray.recycle()
```

```
// One-line version
context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, styleable).also(block).recycle()
```

I'm wonder why verbose block of code looks fine to Android Studio, whereas one-line version highlights **obtainStyledAttributes** and gives following warning:

> This TypedArray should be recycled after use with #recycle()

Does anyone know is it just an Android Studio lint check flaw or something is actually wrong with one-line version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but I believe it's because the static analysis tool can't guarantee that the `TypedArray` returned by `also()` is the same instance as the one returned by `obtainedStyledAttributes()`. It sees that a TypedArray is obtained but can't guarantee that it is recycled, so it issues the warning.

I would hesitate to call this a bug (or "flaw") in the linter, but it does mean that the warning can be ignored in this case.

Comment: If linter can track calls of specific methods (like _obtainStyledAttributes()_ or _recycle()_) it as well should track some things like standard Kotlin function "also" always returning same object, so I would still call it a flaw.
Thanks for your answer, looks to me like a right guess.

Comment: See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139566120, "Fixed for an upcoming 3.6 canary (probably canary 11)".