# Android Studio: How to resolve lint warning with obtainStyledAttributes when recycle is called in try finally block

Tags: android, kotlin, lint

Hi I'm using the following code so in the event of a crash recycle will always be called to free up the memory.

```
context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.example).apply {
    try {
        getDrawable(R.styleable.example_drawable)
    } finally {
        recycle()
    }
}
```

However, for some reason in android studio lint cannot detect the recycle call and it always complains, giving me this warning:

```
This 'TypedArray' should be recycled after use with '#recycle()'
```

I also tried using a Kotlin extension function which should automatically call recycle for me:

```
context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.example).use
{
    it.getDrawable(R.styleable.example_drawable)
}
```

But the lint warning still persists. Any idea what to do?

I am currently using latest versions of Android Studio, Gradle, and Kotlin (3.5.2, 6.0.1, and 1.3.60 respectively)

Is there a way to update lint maybe? Or does it already come with Android Studio.?
Thanks.

*Edit: It seems the .apply is part of the problem. Removing that or the try finally block removes the warning, so somehow you can't have both at the same time. Is this a bug..?

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/57225133/8298909. My guess is that the linter just isn't sophisticated enough to "know" that you're doing the right thing.